# Targeting every n-th li with jQuery :eq

Tags: jquery

Right now, I have a scenario with several UL's with 5 or more LI's - for each UL, I'd like to apply a specific style to the 5th LI.

Using:

`$("ul li:eq(4)")`

Works fine for the first UL on the page, but farts out for the remaining UL's. Any idea how to get this hit all the UL's?

Also, ultimately I'd like to target multiple's of 5 - so the 5th, 10th, 15th items, etc... Not sure how I'd accomplish that without manually stating eq(9), eq(14) etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$("ul li:nth-child(5)")
```

[From jquery website](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index)

Comment: Ah, didn't know nth-child existed... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$('ul li:nth-child(5)')` should provide you with every 5th list item.

As to why jQuery isn't styling all lists in your page, that's odd.  Have you put that declaration in another part of your code that it's only working with a particular part of the page (i.e. have you inadvertently set a more specific context than you meant to)?  You could find out by adding the following to your declaration:

```
console.log ($("ul li:nth-child(5)", document.body).context.nodeName);
```